# Which mountains are rising?

Tags: geology, mountains, mountain-building

The Himalayas are rising--as many people have heard. What other mountain ranges are still rising at a rate faster than they are being worn down by erosion?

Comment: I think the fastest changes might be associated with glacial isostatic adjustments. You can see some rates here: http://www.earth.northwestern.edu/people/seth/Texts/gpsgia.pdf

Answer (score 3):

Anywhere on the planet where there is plate convergence probably has rising mountains, even in the ocean where there is back-arc volcanism, although the mountain building may be out of sight from the sea floor. So that includes all of the Andes, much of the European Alps, New Guinea and Indonesia. But there is not much happening in Africa or Australia.

Comment: I had no success finding a (world) map of this. Can you suggest search terms?

Comment: DO you know of any sources of measurements of said rising mountains?